# How do you pronounce PIPEDA?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm wondering how to pronounce the acronym for Canada's Personal Information Protection and Electronic Documents Act.

PIP eh duh?
pie PEED uh?
other?

Comment: Rhymes with *cicada*.

Comment: EL&U is more a place for asking questions that require the expertise of a linguist, etymologist, or serious language enthusiast – phonetics questions such as *why* we pronounce a word a particular way, or how a pronunciation rule developed. "How to pronounce this word" questions usually won't require expertise. They are also liable to be closed as "general reference" if the word *is* in a dictionary, or as "too localized" if *not* in a dictionary. http://english.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pronounce it either *[pip-EE-duh](http://www.uoguelph.ca/secretariat/pipeda/)* (University of Guelph) or *[PIP-eh-duh](http://www.taylorcga.com/privacy/personal-information-protection-and-electronic-documents-act/)* (Andrew D. Taylor, CGA).  Not all acronyms have set-in-stone pronunciations.

Answer (score 0):

The University of Guelph  informs that PIPEDA is pronounced as /pip'ee-da/

Please check [The University of Guelph’s web site](http://www.uoguelph.ca/secretariat/pipeda/)